# CodeIgniter Multi-site Setup

Tags: database, codeigniter, codebase

I am trying to create multi-site platform using codeigniter. 
Requirements are:
- Same Codebase.
- Same Database.

Just wanted to know how to achieve multi-site platform if we use same database/codebase? 
Is there any way we can create separate tables for each new site i.e wordpress multisite?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have a site in multi language with same DB but separate code.
e.g www.example.com/arabic and www.example.com (english), are u talking about this? If yes then i can help

Comment: To separate data you can use various table prefix for various sites within the same database.

Answer (score 0):

For separate sites you have to create separate directories, and set paths accordingly

```
eg. 
      application/contollers/site1/index.php 
      application/contollers/site2/index.php
```

Same for views and models

For database you can use prefix,

```
eg: if u are creating same site in different languages 

    eng_title
    arabic_title
    eng_description
    arabic_description or arb_description
```

and you can fetch your desired data with your query and condition.

Answer (score 0):

CI tutorial would be helpful for your requirements, please check

[Running Multiple Applications with one CodeIgniter Installation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/managing_apps.html)